# AWS RDS ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol exception

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

While connecting to Oracle 19c database from Java 8 client code, I got error -

> ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol exception

This was resolved by adding `SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION=8` in `sqlnet.ora` file.

Now, when I connect to AWS oracle RDS instance from code running in EC2 instance (RDS and java application running in same subnet), result in same error. Is there an option to add parameter(`SQLNET.ALLOWED_LOGON_VERSION=8`) in AWS Oracle RDS instance? How can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set some SQLNET parameters in Oracle RDS by modifying `sqlnetora.sqlnet.allowed_logon_version_server` and `sqlnetora.sqlnet.allowed_logon_version_client` in your parameter group. (I assume you will then have to restart the database, but I haven't tested changing those values.)

Comment: Thanks Jon it is working file one i modify  parameter sqlnetora.sqlnet.allowed_logon_version_server=8 it was working fine